# Code error structs

Tags: c, struct

when i run the program i get

> card.c:3:23: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
>     printf("%i", attacker->power);

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "card.h"
int main(){
    return 0; 
}
```

card.h:

```
#ifndef CARD_H_FILE
#define CARD_H_FILE
struct card_t {
    char name[10];
    int power, health, mana_cost;
};
int attack(struct card_t *, struct card_t *);
#endif
```

card.c:

```
int attack(struct card_t *attacker, struct card_t *defender){
    printf("%i", attacker->power);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Maybe missing `#include "card.h"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you made omissions when posting your code, `card.c` doesn't include `card.h`, which means it knows nothing about `struct card_t` or its members (`->power`). It also doesn't inlucde `stdio.h`, which means it does not know about `printf()` either.

Remember that C compilers translate source (`.c`) files in isolation, they do not concatenate them. This means the includes in `main.c` do nothing at all for `card.c`.

Answer (score 0):

### include the content of card.c in the file card.h.

card.h

```
#ifndef CARD_H_FILE
#define CARD_H_FILE

struct card_t {
char name[10];
int power, health, mana_cost;
};

int attack(struct card_t *attacker, struct card_t *defender){
printf("%i", attacker->power);
return 1;
}
#endif
```

Comment: You shouldn't put function definitions in header files (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3805833/3235496).